# Showing placeholder image while loading in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to show a placeholder static image in my Windows Phone 8.1 app while loading an image asynchronously from the web.

```
<Image Name="productImage" Source="{Binding ImgUrl}" />
```

The Image is inside a ListView in a DataTemplate.
How to know if the Image finished loading, so I can hide the static Image?

Comment: just hide it when the other image is loaded?

Comment: Ok but the source is set with binding. How to know if the image is asynchronously finished loading, so I can hide the static image?

Comment: hmmm, where are you pulling an image from? Is there built in functions that correlate to the task being finished?

Comment: I download products from an api. For each product i get a Json object which holds the url of the image to be shown. I simply bind that url to the image source in the xaml.

Comment: [This might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016379/wpf-binding-isasync-get-state). You can use [`IsAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync.aspx)

Comment: FallbackValue in your binding base would probably be a good quickie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Performance isn't too critical, you can just place two images on top of each other:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="The Background Image" />
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
</Grid>
```

Your downloaded Image will just overlay the background, once it has loaded.

Will only look fine if your images have a fixed size.

Comment: I wanted to avoid two images, but it seems to be the only working solution so far, so thank you! :)

Comment: The **BitmapImage** class features Events for DownloadProgress and such, so you could (and somebody probably already did) write an adapter that provides a placeholder until the real image has loaded, but there's no easy or xaml only solution.